# .find() muliple classes in one statement with variable

Tags: jquery, html

I have a loop

```
$(".box").find('.video, .print, .web').closest('.box').each(function (index)
 {
     $(this).delay(100 * index).fadeIn(300);
 });
```

This code works just fine.  But I'm calling those 3 classes alot and I wanted to put it into a variable. 
EX:

```
var resetBoxClass = ".print .web .video";

$(".box").find('resetBoxClass').closest('.box').each(function (index)
 {
     $(this).delay(100 * index).fadeIn(300);
 });
```

To my disappoint i cannot get this to work... it is just dumb semantics? can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

comma missing `resetBoxClass = ".print, .web, .video";` **&** `$(".box").find('resetBoxClass')` should be `$(".box").find(resetBoxClass)`

This will help,

Rest as below:

```
var resetBoxClass = ".print, .web, .video";

$(".box").find(resetBoxClass).closest('.box').each(function (index)
 {
     $(this).delay(100 * index).fadeIn(300);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the quotation marks:

```
$(".box").find(resetBoxClass).etc(...
```

With the quotation marks you aren't passing in your variable, you're passing in a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Add commas in the first line between the classes, and loose the quotation marks from the `find()`

Here is the code

```
var resetBoxClass = ".print, .web, .video";

$(".box").find(resetBoxClass).closest('.box').each(function (index)
{
     $(this).delay(100 * index).fadeIn(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should need to cache your element instead of class to execute your code quickly:

```
var yourTarget = $(".box").find('.video, .print, .web').closest('.box');

yourTarget.each(function (index)
 {
     $(this).delay(100 * index).fadeIn(300);
 });
```

Code above will execute faster because your elements is already cached.

Answer (score 0):

@Tats_innit answered your actual question, so I won't rehash that.

This is a slightly clunky construct:

```
$( ".box" ).find( ".video, .print, .web" ).closest( ".box" )

// or

$( ".box" ).find( resetBoxClass ).closest( ".box" )
```

You should be able to do this instead:

```
$( ".box" ).has( ".video, .print, .web" )

// or

$( ".box" ).has( resetBoxClass )
```

> But I'm calling those 3 classes alot and I wanted to put it into a variable.

You mean that you're also using that selector in other parts of your code (that aren't shown in the question), right? For the snippet of code in your question, it doesn't matter whether you pass the selector to `find()` using a literal or a variable. Using a variable would be beneficial if you're using the same selector in other parts of your code. I only mention this on the off chance that you mistakenly think that use of the `each()` loop means that you're "calling those 3 classes alot".